# Vue js MQTT connection problems

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, mqtt

I want to put 'mqtt' value in `span`. But it doesn't work.
I think the loading method is wrong, but I don't know how to do it.
I don't know if the code below will suffice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Someone else coded similar to one page. Someone else's code has a value in 'detail', but my code doesn't. Why?

**HTML**

```html
span{{ detail }}span //empty with nothing
```

**Front script1**

```javascript
export default {
    props: {
        detail: {
            type: Object
        },
        isAdd: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$mqtt.subscribe('#');
    },
    methods: {
        SendData() {
            var temp = [];
            var name = Number(document.getElementsByClassName('name').innerHTML);
            temp.push(name);

            var temp_current = data.payload.Temp_Current;

            var error = data.payload.Error;

            var data = {
                //workcd: this.detail.namemodel,
                Temp_Current: temp_current,
                Error: error,
            };
            data = JSON.stringify(data);

            var pub_name_arr = this.detail.name.split(' ');
            var pub_name = 'CCComandTopic';

            this.$mqtt.publish(
                pub_name + '/' + pub_name_arr[1] + '/' + pub_name_arr[2],
                data,
            );
        },
    }
}
```

**Front script 2**

```javascript
showHotrunner(namemodel, name, data) {
    this.$modal.show(
        Hotrunner,
        {detail: {namemodel, name, data}, isAdd: true}, 
        {width: '1040', height: '700', draggable: true},
    );
    const canvas = document.getElementById('three-canvas');
    canvas.classList.add('noclick');
}
```

**Back**

```javascript
var device = msg.topic.split("/")[2]
if(device == "hopper")
{
    var temp_current = msg.payload.Temp_Current
    var error = msg.payload.error
        
    msg = {
        topic : "CCComandTopic/hopper/1",
        payload : {
            ID: id,
            "Error": error, 
            Temp_Current: temp_current,
               
        }
    }.
    node.send(msg)
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it's not really clear how your code fits together e.g. where is `showHotrunner` called from, why is there a `publish` in your front end, why is the backend relevant (you can send test messages using [something like this](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/)). Test the parts individually (e.g. if `showHotrunner` is not being called then simplify it to a `console.log` to avoid unnecessary code in the example).

Comment: @Brits  Thanks for pointing it out. I will solve this problem myself by ignorance of which code to inform.....